# Help With PHP Pagination Script For Flat File Database

Tags: php, database, pagination, flat-file

I have a few questions regarding a PHP Pagination Script For Flat File Database I found.
I have posted the script below.

```
<?php 
echo '<html><body>';

// Data, normally from a flat file or some other source  
$data = "Item1|Item2|Item3|Item4|Item5|Item6|Item7|Item8|Item9|Item10";  
// Put our data into an array  
$dataArray = explode('|', $data);  
// Get the current page  
$currentPage = trim($_REQUEST[page]);  
// Pagination settings  
$perPage = 3;  
$numPages = ceil(count($dataArray) / $perPage);  
if(!$currentPage || $currentPage > $numPages)  
    $currentPage = 0;  
$start = $currentPage * $perPage;  
$end = ($currentPage * $perPage) + $perPage;  
// Extract ones we need  
foreach($dataArray AS $key => $val)  
{  
    if($key >= $start && $key < $end)  
        $pagedData[] = $dataArray[$key];  
}

foreach($pagedData AS $item)  
    echo '<a href="/'. $item .'/index.php">'. $item .'</a><br>';

if($currentPage > 0 && $currentPage < $numPages)  
    echo '<a href="?page=' . ($currentPage - 1) . '">« Previous page</a><br>';  
if($numPages > $currentPage && ($currentPage + 1) < $numPages)  
    echo '<a href="?page=' . ($currentPage + 1) . '" class="right">Next page »</a><br>';

echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

My first problem seems to be in line 9. I could change the line to:

```
$currentPage = trim(@$_REQUEST[page]);
```

But this change won't fix the error, it will just hide it. What needs to be done to line 9 to rid my page of the error?

Secondly, I would like to fetch the data on line 5 in a different way. I would like to get the data from a text file, let's call it "items.txt", that has entries like below, one per line.

```
Fun
Games
Toys
Sports
Fishing
Pools
Boats
```

Please recommend alternate code to fetch the desired data.

Lastly, I would like to include links to the "First page" and "Last page" as well as "Previous page" and "Next page", as is the current code.

I apologize for my sloppy posting, but would be real appreciative of anybody who could help me understand the changes needed to produce my desired results. Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem With Line 9**

`$_REQUEST[page]` has two separate problems.

1) `page` is being read as the name of a constant because it is not quoted. PHP then notices there is no constant called `page`, so it takes a guess that you meant the string `page` -- which it would be if `page` was quoted -- and triggers an error to notify you. Therefore, use `$_REQUEST['page']` instead.

2) `'page'` is not necessarily a key of `$_REQUEST` because the data is not guaranteed to be given. Therefore, you cannot refer to `$_REQUEST['page']` before  you ensure that it exists. This may be done by `isset($_REQUEST['page'])`.

Your final code should look something like this, then.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
    $currentPage = $_REQUEST['page'];
} else {
    $currentPage = 'some default value';
}
```

**Problem With Data Source**

The `file()` function reads the lines of a file into an array -- for example, the fourth value of the array is also the fourth line in the file. Therefore, you can set `$dataArray` simply as `$dataArray = file('text.dat');`.

Comment: Thanks! So far so good. I have fixed the error as described and I am now getting the data from a text file. What if the current page URL contains a query string of it own? This will be a problem, Right? What to do then?

Comment: I do not fully understand your new problem. As to the nature of Stackoverflow, it is highly beneficial to ask each question separately. Otherwise, it makes it very difficult for future searchers to find the answers.

Comment: Let's say this script is displayed on a page called: site.com/index.php?member=156 After clicking the Next Page link, the member variable will be gone. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, so link to `site.com/index.php?member=156` instead.